# Need help to automate Multi Factor Authentication testing?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, multi-factor-authentication

We have a requirement - When user registers or logs in to the website from a new browser or device then an authentication code is sent to email or via text. Once the authentication is completed, the system captures the browser fingerprint.

On subsequent login, if the same browser on the same device is used then the multi-factor authentication is not triggered. Whereas, if subsequent login is from a new browser or device then MFA is triggered again.

With the help of our dev team, we have handled the MFA automation. However, we are struggling with the 2nd part where subsequent login related scenarios have to be tested. We have our framework built in Selenium with java and need help with this.

To be precise we need to handle below 2 test cases -

1. If subsequent login is from same browser device then MFA should not occur.
2. If subsequent login is from a different browser or device then MFA should occur.

I am looking for some solution, where we don't need to change the browser. Test case 1 is a cake walk. The problem is with test case 2. How do we make the MFA system feel that the subsequent request is coming from a different browser/device?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think multithreading will be the answer for test case 2 so you can spawn two browsers at the same time. Example:

Thread class

```
public class BrowserThread implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
          WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
          // do authentication steps
          // verify if successful
    }
}
```

Then your main function

```
Thread browserOne = new Thread(new BrowserThread(), "BrowserOneThread");
browserOne.start();
Thread browserTwo = new Thread(new BrowserThread(), "BrowserTwoThread");
browserTwo.start();
```

This is just a very simple example to show you how it works in general. If you want more control for each thread execution, I'd suggest to look at `java.util.concurrent.Future`